# Power Amplifier Modification

Tags: amplifier

I am trying to build this amplifier. Looking at the diagram, am pretty sure how it works, but is there a way I can modify this variable resistor with some fixed ones?[image]

Comment: Yes, after you have adjusted it for correct operation and measured its resistance. Your question is missing an attribution for the schematic and this is required on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable resister is for setting up the idle current in the main powermosfet bank .More resistance means more gate source volts meaning more current .Mosfets are very spready so a fixed resister would not be good for a population of amplifiers,hence the variable resister .Once you have set the idle current you could use a fixed resister of the same value as the variable one .This fixed value would be good for your amp with your fets but probably not for somebody else .Fixed resisters are more reliable than pots .If you had to replace the expensive fets your resister value would probably change .